# Rails - group by results of an aggregate function?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say I have a table of Purchases that contain a Customer `customer_id` and the money they spent on the purchase `price`. I want to sum the total spent by each customer and then find the frequency of those sums.

I tried something like:

```
Purchase.
group(:customer_id).
select("SUM(price)").
group("SUM(price)").
count
```

but received the error `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  aggregate function calls cannot be nested`

There's a two step process in which I pluck `"SUM(price)"` as an array and convert it to a hash with the summed price as the key and the frequency as the value, but I was wondering if there was a one-step query using the Rails syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have other columns on that table ?

Try to group them as well.

```
Purchase.select("SUM(price),purchase_id").group_by(:purchase_id)
```

Make sure you take only columns you need and group them.

Comment: This is just an example, and in my actual data I have 11 columns including some metadata like created and updated times. How would grouping by those overcome the issue of nested groups?

Comment: Because when u r summing u r actually grouping them by their sum. So that many of columns won't be able to correspond to that.
So what I am recomending is to select colums that you need like above. Edited version.